# Is this a valid representation of last digit $7^{2013}$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

As we are looking at $\Z_{10}$ or $\pmod{10}$ we can redefine this as}$$7^{2013} = 7^{2\cdot 1006}\cdot 7 = 7^2(7^{1006})\cdot 7=[-3^{2}]^{1006} \cdot 7=[1]\cdot 7=7$$

Comment: $7^{2.1006} \ne 7^2(7^{1006})$

Comment: @mama True, but that would be more relevant if the dot were a bit higher :-)

Answer (score 2):

You have
$$7^{2013} = 49^{1006}\cdot 7 = 2401^{503}\cdot 7$$
Notice that $2401^{503}{\rm mod} 10 = 1$.  So the last digit is 7.

If you are doubting Thomas, here is Python at work.

```
   >>> print(7**2013)
    1521789378959156124545770305635446432064494754037453756264116722949754
29281570832529972184615904149062235836516258391699002694536583848906673262
63169837311191007353214497528569629890523887048942817148718270823506508645
15611185002755678844217387697896698124077871194231015461122449543488680101
24139388406446256149244913197561081838608846797766842996701433516152812124
09257502245274219473715467971910010976888281677594746650240240752377590532
00143314552339241406124364947956916809199130287169576938149841075352254361
79560619158784500013252582623320896839584055896739571749107961688363026602
68593321810633873421881116227321814972125164724299300630091253721258617077
07409976481591786264522846292440169478632349942854830166726374972817238056
86050351599025617298323468965044384205927671043097289948376260370579679188
14691016676325426079246482885456743771220187151416539907327344331774353083
70156612337655897534455074220694005085284446233466076821496588133738177266
57930454017789251450051994148397416711750548541524455917297449179981379285
493466619082320962134873758853315841135812801455732800054086868044964520351
833702944033741467062848505290170525811163965193255262169315868376431065875
107647823863886880426502464198911459348131722975475700761189633434392574676
468966479748889731954649008753212606961753476614713545365099895947055189883
847685698816353607123079996623689959802276284899326609352501644952043252361
451662350429978480215499188872019362909671472118073580882582996115943641298
382818560186972363954520051100136712275841394466762769750843545459435224083
799936690427958528781831887727871720354721014897799358531489301393225256459
549932452298025728265444784456715661711696974318492979524291297410407
>>>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your argument is not right; the rules for exponents are $a^{bc} = (a^b)^c$ and $a^{b+c}=a^ba^c$.

Of course there are *some* values of $a$, $b$, and $c$ for which we happen to have $a^{bc} = a^{b+c} \pmod{10}$, but in any case you have not justified the second equality in your argument.

Answer (score 0):

for 7^1 = 7(last digit)
  ^2 = 9
  ^3 = 3
  ^4 = 1
   .
   .
   . and so on until 9. Therefore, for example, for 7^8, we will have 1 as last digit since after every 4 values, last digit will be sanme.
therefore,
7^2013 = 7^(2012) * 7^1 = 1 * 7(last digits) = 7